# Managed memory leak in TabControl

Tags: vb.net, memory-leaks, tabcontrol

I know this is similar to questions asked in the past, but none of the supplied answers have worked for my project.

I'm seeing a managed memory leak in the Performance Monitor when removing TabPages from a TabControl.

In order to simplify the troubleshooting, I created a simple test program to add and remove a TabPages containing a WebBrowser.  I also added controls to manually collect garbage, clear the TabPages in the control and delete the control.

Performance Monitor for test application: http://image.prntscr.com/image/77d56b7dd6534b07a55506c825b5f772.png

None of these processes freed up any memory, so I must be missing something very basic.

Code for adding the TabPage and Form:

```
Private Sub MemoryTestToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MemoryTestToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim pageNew As New TabPage("Memory Test")
    Dim formNew As New MemoryTest

    formNew.TopLevel = False
    formNew.Parent = pageNew
    formNew.AutoSize = True
    formNew.Show()

    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(pageNew)
End Sub
```

Code for removing the TabPage and Form:

```
Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    CType(Me.Parent.Parent, TabControl).TabPages.Remove(Me.Parent)

    Dim pageParent As TabPage = CType(Me.Parent, TabPage)

    Me.Parent = Nothing

    pageParent.Dispose()

    WebBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank")

    For Each item As Control In Controls
        Me.Controls.Remove(item)
        item.Dispose()
    Next

    Me.Dispose()
End Sub
```

(I know I'm going overboard a bit, but I'm trying everything I can think of to let the GC know that nothing on the Form or TabPage is still needed).

Any help would be monumentally appreciated as my actual application is being used by some people on very resource-limited machines.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: GC do not free memory right after object was disposed/removed. It will remove it when "time will come". With small application it can happened after application closed.

Comment: I would suggest actually user testing on a machine comparable to those your client is using - it may be that the performance monitor is reporting things that will not adversely affect the UX. And, as Fabio mentioned, the GC knows that those items need to be collected, but stages collection because garbage collection is an expensive operation, and would actually consume more CPU cycles. Let the framework do its thing.

Comment: I am testing the test application on my own machine, and am manually calling GC.Collect and waiting.  Shouldn't that fire off GC?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the `.Remove` with a `.Dispose` seems to have solved the issue for me.

You have to use `Tabcontrol.TabPages('tabpagename').dispose`